# Green line on whatsapp video call after some time

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video-calling

When I have a video call, after some time, a green line will appear on the left portion of the screen.
It seems to appear from the other party's image.
Below is the screenshot:

[image]

When I switch the display, it still appears (it is showing a smaller green line as the other party's display was displayed in a smaller box).

[image]

Any idea what caused this and how to resolve it?

Comment: Looks to me like a glitch in the video codec. This may happen if the video data is transmitted via UDP and some packets git lost. Usually they should go away after a few seconds respectively after the next key-frame (a full image in difference to other frames that just transmit the changed parts of the image) has been transmitted.

Comment: Well, this one did not go away after a few seconds, it seems persistent for quite long time.